# Problems when importing Slick

Tags: playframework-2.0, h2, slick, slick-3.0

I get a compilation error when I try to import these two API's in my application.scala:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

I'm following the Slick documentation on http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/gettingstarted.html#database-configuration.
This is the error I get when i try compile it on localhost:9000, compilation error. 
[image]
My build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you follow the 3.1.0 documentation but have 2.1.0 as a dependency?

Comment: i feel so stupid, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the H2 Driver as dependency in your build.sbt

```
"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.190"
```